# IRibbonUI document load event

Tags: vba, excel-iribbonui

I'm wondering if someone can help me out with a VBA issue -- I haven't written VBA in over 20 years and I'm stuck.

I've created a ribbon button and I need the button greyed out if a word document is open from a local drive or file share.  I need the button active if the document is open from SharePoint or OneDrive.

```
Dim Rib As IRibbonUI
Public MyTag As String

'Callback for customUI.onLoad
Sub RibbonOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
Set Rib = ribbon

End Sub

Sub GetEnabledMacro(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef Enabled)
If MyTag = "Enable" Then
    Enabled = True
Else
    If control.Tag Like MyTag Then
        Enabled = True
    Else
        Enabled = False
    End If
End If
End Sub

Sub RefreshRibbon(Tag As String)
MyTag = Tag
If Rib Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Error, Save/Restart your workbook" & vbNewLine & _
    "Visit this page for a solution:     Else
    Rib.Invalidate
End If
End Sub

Sub EnabledAllControls()
'Enable all controls
Call RefreshRibbon(Tag:="*")
End Sub

Sub DisableAllControls()
'Disable all controls
Call RefreshRibbon(Tag:="")
End Sub
```

Then I'm using this if statement to test file location.  It just doesn't fire?

```
Sub AutoOpen()
If InStr(ActiveDocument.Path, "http") = 1 Then
Call EnabledAllControls
Else

Call DisableAllControls

End If
End Sub
```

I've been working on this for over a week and I'm under the gun to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

The following is untested, but I've made a lot of ribbons and it feels right. It's all code that you had with what I think are the unnecessary parts deleted:

```
Dim Rib As IRibbonUI

'Callback for customUI.onLoad
Sub RibbonOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
Set Rib = ribbon
End Sub

Sub GetEnabledMacro(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef Enabled)
Enabled = If InStr(ActiveDocument.Path, "http") = 1
End Sub

Sub AutoOpen()
If Rib Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Error, Save/Restart your workbook" & vbNewLine & _ 
    "Visit this page for a solution:"
Else
    Rib.Invalidate
End If
End Sub
```

Basically, you just need the ribbon object (check), the Event that triggers the setting of the state (check) and the logic to determine the state (check). You don't need a global variable.

Of course your Ribbon XML must assign `Sub GetEnabledMacro` to the control's `GetEnabled` property.